# Moving CakePhp Project to FTP server

Tags: php, cakephp, ftp

I have a project and I want to upload it to my web server. But i get these errors :

> Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\ums\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\vhosts\ajansimaj.com\httpdocs\ums2\webroot\index.php on line 83
>
> Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\ums\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\vhosts\ajansimaj.com\httpdocs\ums2\webroot\index.php on line 83
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\wamp\www\ums\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in C:\inetpub\vhosts\ajansimaj.com\httpdocs\ums2\webroot\index.php on line 83
>
> Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors root directory. in C:\inetpub\vhosts\ajansimaj.com\httpdocs\ums2\webroot\index.php on line 88

What can i do to fix these problems ? Thank you

Comment: the files are not being included. Can you give us the code that u used to include those files? (`inlude`, `include_once`, `require` or `require_once`)

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want to see the codes which is in webroot/index.php ? I run this project in my localhost but now i want to upload it to my ftp server. And when I uploaded it, these errors apper on my browser.

Comment: that would help a lot

Comment: http://codepaste.net/67zuy7, I do not know the rules. If this link is forbidden to share on this page, please warn me.

Comment: ^ Links are fine as secondary material, but it is much better to post short code samples directly into your question. This is mainly because external links may not always be available, and the question becomes not useful if the link dies. Bear in mind that questions here are intended to be a useful Q&A for posterity, not a forum to answer highly localised questions (so, make questions as generalised as you can!).

Answer (score 0):

As the error say:

> CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of
>   CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to
>   the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors
>   root directory. in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\ajansimaj.com\httpdocs\ums2\webroot\index.php on
>   line 88

You should change the line

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'C:' . DS . 'wamp' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'ums' . DS . 'lib');
```

in your C:\inetpub\vhosts\ajansimaj.com\httpdocs\ums2\webroot\index.php file into:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'C:' . DS . 'inetpub' . DS . 'vhosts' . DS . 'ajansimaj.com' . DS . 'httpdocs' . DS . 'ums2' . DS . 'lib');
```

and it should be working...

Answer (score 0):

### Restore your index.php file

Unfortunately, it looks like you've been bitten by the way that `cake bake <project>` would previously create an index.php file that was install-specific. To correct this, copy the `app/webroot/index.php` file from your cake install, or from [the source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/index.php) (ensure you use the same version of cake as you have installed), in this way the same file will work wherever it is located.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to clear the caches in /app/tmp/cache/persistent